# How to display image if path is in json

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in Angular and I am using Angular 8
I have list of path of images in 'dataSource' variable in JSON format like this:

```
hotdeals: Array(4) 
    0: {uri: "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal1.png", id: "2"}
    1: {uri: "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal2.png", id: "3"}
    2: {uri: "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal3.png", id: "4"}
    3: {uri: "/Home/HotDeals/hotdeal4.png", id: "6"}
```

How can i show all this images on HTML if my base url is "http://localhost" and file path is above in JSON.
Note: Image path may increase or decrease. Means this time 4 image i got, but if i get 5 image path. So how can i handle this?

> dashboard.component.html

```
ngOnInit() 
  {
    this.apiService.getHotDeals('pop').subscribe(home=>{
      this.dataSource=home;
console.log(this.dataSource)    

}
```

> dashboard.component.html

```
<owl-carousel [options]="{items:3, dots:true, navigation:true}"
          [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']" >          
                    <div class="best-deals-single"><a><img src="{{this.dataSource}}" height="300" width="200" alt=""></a></div>               
 </owl-carousel>
```

Screenshot of console of dataSource
[image]

Comment: you need to put your images into assets folder in your project, change the images path to the `/assets/path-to-image`. that's should work

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan image is stored on server. and i am getting path and file name from DB. Here I used localhost to not mention my server address

Comment: In that case, you have to add the server URL before the image Uri when rendering them

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan It's not working. can you see my json. It's in hotdeals=>uri

Comment: @Manisha please can you share the screenshot of `console.log(this.dataSource)`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan added it

Comment: @Manisha Chris has been updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a loop to display all images:

**component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class YourComponentComponent {
  imgHost = environment.imgHost;
}
```

**template:**

```
<owl-carousel
  *ngIf="dataSource.hotdeals"
  [options]="{items:3, dots:true, navigation:true}"
  [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']"
  [items]="dataSource.hotdeals" 
>
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let img of dataSource.hotdeals">
    <div style="align-content: center;">
      <img style="height: 260px; width: 100%;" [src]="imgHost + img.uri" />
    </div>
  </div>
</owl-carousel>
```

**environment.json**

```
export const environment = {
  imgHost: 'https://example.com'
};
```

and if your images are on the same server as the application

**environment.prod.json**

```
export const environment = {
  imgHost: ''
};
```

Comment: My Image path is in hotdeals=>uri ....You can see my json data

Comment: @Manisha try to change `[src]="'https://example.com/' + img.url"`

Comment: Chris please change the [src]="imgHost + img" to `[src]="imgHost + img.uri"`